# send mail then pass value of form?

Tags: php, forms, email

this is my code

```
    <?php
ob_start();
  $x_login = $_POST['x_login'];
  $x_amount = $_POST['x_amount'];
  $x_show_form = $_POST['x_show'];

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "abcd@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    header("Location: www.example.com");
    exit();
    }


?>
<html>
<body>
                            <form action="" class="contactForm" name="cform" method="post">
                                            <input name="x_login" value="<?php echo $x_login ?>" type="hidden"> 

                                            <input name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $x_amount ?>" type="hidden"> 

                                            <input name="x_show" value="<?php echo $x_show ?>" type="hidden"> 

                                    <div style="width:55%; margin:0 auto;" class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="fname">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <span class="name-missing">Please enter your First Name</span>  
                                        <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="width:55%; margin:0 auto;" class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="lname">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <span class="name-missing">Please enter your Last Name</span>  
                                        <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="width:55%; margin:0 auto;" class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="e-mail">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail</span> 
                                        <input id="e-mail" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">   
                            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

its a page which i am using to send e-mail and also receiving values of `x_login, x_amount, x_show` from previous form then it goes to  the contactForm where you can see hidden fields, then below its a contact form.

Now i want that when user submit the form then email send(which is working) then page redirects to the other website and get the value of hidden fields which i want to know how will it be done.

Comment: You could store it in a temporary cookie/session and retrieve it from there.

Comment: i can't because i don't have access of the retrieving file of (www.example.com)

Comment: So if I get this right the person submits this form and then you want it to email (which works now) then forward data to the other website?

Comment: Well if you dont have the access to a page, you probably shouldn't be passing values from your page to it. You could also look up how to post parameters to an exteral page from PHP I guess.

Comment: @Rasclatt hmmm right

Comment: To pass data (provided it doesn't need to be a secret), you can forward in your header function: `header("Location: http://www.example.com?data1=whatever&data2=something");`

Comment: we can only pass value by its parameters which is x_login, x_amount, x_show they are using POST method

Comment: Then you would probably have to do some sort of `cURL` function and send with a post.

Comment: can you tell me a simple example `cURL`